# Error when adding FIRST record to table

Tags: php, mysql

Ok. I ran into an issue. My code is able to insert records into my *merchandise* table. I truncated the table and a record is still inserted into the table but with an error "**Undefined variable last_id**". I assume that this is because when the table was truncate, there isn't a previous id since the record being inserted is the FIRST. Can someone help me resolve this issue. Thanks!

```
 $sql = "SELECT m_id FROM merchandise";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $last_id = $row["m_id"];
    }
    $next_id = $last_id+1;
    $conc = number_format($next_id/100,2,'-','');

    $query = "INSERT INTO merchandise (mfr,type,description,mer_sku,price,qty) ";
    $query .="VALUES ('$mfr','$type','$desc','MR{$mfr}{$conc}','$price','$qty')";
    $add_sku_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare last id as zero in case there are no rows.

```
$last_id = 0;
$sql = "SELECT m_id FROM merchandise";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$last_id = $row["m_id"];
}
$next_id = $last_id+1;
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something easy!! Thanks.

Comment: btw, you may very well want to look into using a primary key as an auto incrementer, though i confess, i'm not entirely sure what you were planning on doing with that $last_id.  also, looping over the entire table to get the max(id) can be done in one pass by **$sql = 'select max(m_id) max from merchandise";** and then just using $row['max'];